# Is b⊢C∧¬b⊢C∧b⇒C∧¬b⇒C possible?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

Are there any cases where b and C are real world statements where b⊢C∧¬b⊢C∧b⇒C∧¬b⇒C **where b and C are not tautologies**? It may seem like a silly question, but after searching hard and deep, I couldn't find an answer! Please help me with this question.

Comment: Are the two turnstyles (⊢) supposed to be there? I often think of the turnstyle as separating the premises from the conclusion.

Comment: @FrankHubeny in this context I am using the turnstile for provability

Comment: Your notation is rather weird, but if I understand it correctly, the answer is yes, this would be possible provided C is a tautology.

Comment: @MathBob, there should still be only one turnstyle in a sequent.

Comment: @Bumble I will fix my question

Comment: The formula is wrongly written and it is impossible to parse it. **⊢** is not a connective; thus we can read it as **b⊢C** and **¬b⊢C** and **b⇒C∧¬b⇒C**; but in this case it is lacking a "verb" attached to the last formula.

Comment: doesnt it mean using just translating,"C is provable from b and C is provable from not-b and b implies C and not-b implies C"?

Comment: It can be read as b⊢C and ¬b⊢C and b⇒C and ¬b⇒C

Comment: which can be simplified to b⊢C and ¬b⊢C

Comment: No, it doesn't.  If that is what you want to say, just say it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume classical propositional calculus.

If **C** is a *tautology*, then **⊨ C**, and thus **B ⊢ C** for **B** whatever, and thus **⊢ B → C**.

If not, if we have both **B ⊢  C** and **¬B ⊢ C** we apply the Deduction Theorem and we get :

> **⊢ ¬B → C** and **⊢ B → C**.

Now, using [Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) **⊢ ¬B ∨ B**, we can use [Disjunction Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) to conclude with **⊢ C**.

But if **C** is not a tautology, this contradicts the soundness of the calculus.